# Encrypt the message NEED HELP by translating the letters into numbers..answer is UTTQ CTOA...how?

Tags: encryption, discrete-mathematics

Encrypt the message NEED HELP by translating the letters into numbers, applying the 
encryption function f (p) = (3p + 7) mod 26, and then translating the numbers back into 
letters. 
Ans: Encrypted form: UTTQ CTOA.

could someone please explain to me how they got this answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to assign a number to each letter:

A = 0; B = 1; C = 2 ....

then you apply the function to the numbers you get and convert it back to letters:

N would be 13, so 13 * 3 = 39, + 7 = 46
then mod 26 = 20

converting back, 20 = U

If you do it on all the letters of your sentence you'll have the encrypted form

and here the C# code to do this:

```
    private static string encrypt(string s)
    {
        char[] tmp = new char[s.Length];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (char c in s)
        {
            tmp[i] = (char)((((c - 'A') * 3 + 7) % 26) + 'A');
            i++;
        }

        return new string(tmp);
    }
```

and here your decrypt function (ok this one is messy but works):

```
    private static string decrypt(string s)
    {
        string res = s;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            res = encrypt(res);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: thanks...where did you apply 20 to get U ? that's exactly what i did not understand

Comment: just write all the letters from A to Z and write the numbers (starting with 0) in front of them, you'll see that U will have 20 in front of it